# Howto: on linux user login → auto execute command (eg. top) → auto logout when execution of command stops

Tags: linux

Can I , on linux , create a user and configure it so, that when I login using ssh, an command is executed and when this command has finished the user is forced to logout.

Comment: If this user is only going to log in via SSH, you can set the command as its shell (ie, it runs the command directly instead of running bash): `usermod -s /path/to/command userid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is perfectly possible. I use the following to execute [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) automatically on login and automatically quit the session when quitting screen:

```
cat << _EOF_ > /etc/profile.d/00-micha.sh
# Autostart screen and auto logout
[ "\$TERM" != 'screen' ] && screen -U -S sshscreen -d -R && exit
_EOF_
```

To make it more specific for the current user on SSH sessions only:

```
cat << _EOF_ >> ~/.profile
# Start myCommand on SSH login sessions and exit when myCommand stops
[ -n "\${SSH_TTY}" ] && myCommand && exit
_EOF_
```

- This adds the code lines to the end of the current users `.profile` file which gets executed/sourced on all login sessions, which should be the case when logging in via SSH.
- It checks whether it is an SSH session by checking a set `SSH_TTY` variable, which is set automatically by at least OpenSSH and Dropbear SSH servers. There are other possibilities but this one is fast and should and reliable.
- It executes `myCommand` (replace with your command + arguments in case of course), and exits when the command exits **successfully**. I prefer it in this way so that in case of error you might want to investigate the issue interactively instead of being unable to login via SSH with this users (auto logout on command crash). However if you even want it to logout/exit in case of `myCommand` error, you can adjust the code line to:

  ```
  [ -n "${SSH_TTY}" ] && { myCommand; exit; }
  ```

`Bash` and `zsh` have a bunch of other files that are sourced during different kinds of logins/sessions, so if you need it more specific, I can add further details, or you might want the shells man pages, e.g. for bash ("Invocation" section): https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash